# SOLVED - Communicate Between Unrelated Components - Trailhead- Error with LightningMessageChannel

Tags: salesforcedx, trailhead

Check the answer for the solution:

I'm working on the [Communicate Between Unrelated Components](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/projects/communicate-between-lightning-web-components/communicate-between-unrelated-components?trail_id=build-lightning-web-components) module on Trailhead.

I'm stuck at step 1:

1. In Visual Studio Code, in the default folder, create a folder named
   messageChannels.
2. In the messageChannels folder, create a file named
   Count_Updated.messageChannel-meta.xml.
3. In Count_Updated.messageChannel-meta.xml, paste this code:

   [image]

That gives me this error:

*cvc-elt.1.a: Cannot find the declaration of element 'LightningMessageChannel'.xml(cvc-elt.1.a)*

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found the solution elsewhere:

This can be achieved with these two terminal commands from within the project folder:

> git pull

> sfdx force:source:deploy -m LightningMessageChannel

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a blocking error for that Trailhead, it's issued from VS Code. You'll be able to save and deploy it.
An extension of VS Code is trying to validate your xml and doesn't find the definition of that element.
If you want to disable it click on `File` menu, then on `Preferences` and open `Settings`. Search for 'xml validation' and disable it.